# Getting my driver's license notarized in Turkey

Tags: driving-license, turkey

I'm Lebanese living in Turkey. After doing some research, I found out that I can use my drivers license here as long as I get it translated and notarized. I was wondering if anyone can help me learn how much would it cost me to get it translated and notarized?

Comment: See also http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/is-a-turkish-driving-license-required-as-a-foreign-national-to-drive-in-turkey-l

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the International Driving Permit, which is honored in Turkey and many other countries. This, carried along with your valid Lebanese driving license, permits you to drive in most countries.

In Lebanon you can [obtain an IDP](http://www.isf.gov.lb/en/ways) from:

> Accredited vehicle driving schools;
>   Bureau of the Traffic, Trucks and Vehicles Management Authority (Nafaa) and its branches all over Lebanon

In practice you can apply for your IDP at [LibanPost post offices](https://www.libanpost.com/Services/NonGovernmentServices/SNGS_InternationalDrivingLicense/tabid/263/Default.aspx), and your application will be processed through the [Lebanese Automobile and Tourism Club](http://www.atcl.org/Auto.aspx?sec=3), which may take 5 working days. It is a bit cheaper if you are an ATCL member, and if you apply at ATCL you can have it instantly. The cost appears to be 150.000LL if applied for directly through ATCL, or 140.000LL for ATCL members.

As far as I know you cannot apply for it outside Lebanon.